# Joining/Appending different tables together in Microsoft sql server

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, hibernate

Hai all I have 3 different tables in a database in MS SQL SERVER.

1. LAB_patientreg
2. patient_master
3. patient_address

This *LAB_patientreg* and *patient_master* are two tables containing patient details (the patients in both table are different, *LAB_patientreg* is the table regarding the patients who registered in lab directly and *patient_master* is about the patient registered to hospital as *out patient* or *in patient* at the reception) and *patient_address* is the table which contains the address of patients registered in the table *patient_master*.

In some cases I need the data of all the patients including *LAB_patientreg* and *patient_master* with *patient_address*. My aim is to create a view which have all the values in this table together(ie if *patient_master* have 50 rows and *LAB_patientreg* have 32 rows the resultant view should be 82 rows) and also the number and type of columns is limited to that of  *LAB_patientreg* but it is not working, is it possible to create a view as I said? If not what should I do to obtain such view? Thanks in advance for helping me.

Structure of tables are as follows,

**patient_master**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[patient_master](
    [pid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [date_created] [date] NULL,
    [title] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [fname] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [mname] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [lname] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [addr_id] [int] NULL,
    [sex] [char](1) NULL,
    [dob] [date] NULL,
    [dobType] [tinyint] NULL,
    [marital_status] [int] NULL,
    [religion] [int] NULL,
    [caste] [int] NULL,
    [aadhar_no] [varchar](16) NULL,
    [mother_name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [guardian_name] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [guardian_rltn] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [allow_sms] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [allow_email] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [occupation] [int] NULL,
    [monthly_income] [int] NULL,
    [financial_review_date] [datetime] NULL,
    [race] [int] NULL,
    [language] [int] NULL,
    [referrer] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [referrer_id] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [interpretter] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [interpretter_id] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [deceased_date] [date] NULL,
    [deceased_reason] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [created_by] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [changed_by] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [date_changed] [datetime] NULL,
    [voided] [tinyint] NULL,
    [voided_by] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [date_voided] [datetime] NULL,
    [void_reason] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [block] [tinyint] NULL,
    [aliasname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [confidential] [int] NULL,
    [hospno] [char](8) NULL, PRIMARY KEY(pid)
);
```

**patient_address**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[patient_address](
    [pres_house_no] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [pres_city] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [pres_street] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [pres_district] [int] NULL,
    [pres_pincode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [perm_house_no] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [perm_city] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [perm_street] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [perm_district] [int] NULL,
    [perm_pincode] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [home_phone] [varchar](11) NULL,
    [mobile_phone] [varchar](11) NULL,
    [other_phone] [varchar](11) NULL,
    [work_phone] [varchar](11) NULL,
    [email] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [emerg_cntct] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [emerg_cntct_rltn] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [emerg_cntct_num] [varchar](11) NULL,
    [pres_place] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [perm_place] [varchar](255) NULL,
    [addr_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [pid] [int] NULL,
    [active] [char](1) NULL,
    [phone_type] [varchar](4) NULL, , PRIMARY KEY(addr_id)
);
```

**LAB_patientreg**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LAB_patientreg](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [patientid] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [title] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [fname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [mname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [lname] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [dob] [smalldatetime] NULL,
    [gender] [char](2) NULL,
    [mstatus] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [idtype] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [idno] [varchar](25) NULL,
    [mtongue] [varchar](35) NULL,
    [address] [varchar](300) NULL,
    [phtype] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [phno] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [emailid] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [smsstatus] [int] NULL,
    [mailstatus] [int] NULL,
    [status] [int] NULL,
    [regcenter] [varchar](30) NULL,
    [regdate] [smalldatetime] NULL, PRIMARY KEY(patientid)
);
```

I had tried the following

```
Select patientid,title, fname, mname, lname, NULL As religion from LAB_patientreg WHERE 1=1
Union All  
Select pid,title, fname, mname, lname, religion from patient 
INNER JOIN patient_address ON patient.pid = patient_address.pid WHERE 1=1
```

When executing this, an error occurs as Error code 209, SQL state S1000: Ambiguous column name 'pid'"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you maybe want an Union Select here?

Containing both Table Data in one View, plus being able to add condition to the Second Table. it would be like this:

```
Select title, fname, mname, lname, NULL As religion,  patientid As pid from dbo.LAB_patientreg WHERE 1=1
UNION  
Select title, fname, mname, lname, religion, convert(varchar, patient_master.pid) As pid from dbo.patient_master 
INNER JOIN patient_address ON patient_master.pid = patient_address.pid
WHERE 1=1
```

(Just Replace the where 1=1 with your condition)

With the Union Select: Make Sure you have The Same Column Names on **both** tables. if you dont have the field in the other table, you can use `AlternateFieldname As TheFieldNameINeed` As for example The field `Null As religion`

Edit: Either you can use `Union` to get all different values or `Union All` to get ALL values of both table.

Comment: I need to map '[pid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL' _in_ '[dbo].[patient_master]'  _and_ '[patientid] [varchar](15) NOT NULL' _in_ '[LAB_patientreg]'. But this error occurs "Error code 209, SQL state S1000: Ambiguous column name 'pid'". Can you help me please.

Comment: oh i see, ill use an Edit2 in a few in my post, maybe that will do.

Comment: `Select patientid,title, fname, mname, lname, NULL As religion from LAB_patientreg WHERE 1=1
Union All 
Select pid,title, fname, mname, lname, religion from patient 
INNER JOIN patient_address ON patient.pid = patient_address.pid
WHERE 1=1`  When executing this error occurs as Error code 209, SQL state S1000: Ambiguous column name 'pid'"

Comment: oh i see, you want both on the same column. i'll edit again. - your exact error comes from the second Select, where you are using a join. you need to define where the field 'pid' comes from, either patient_adress or patient_master

Comment: If I make change it like this `Select patientid,title, fname, mname, lname, NULL As religion from LAB_patientreg WHERE 1=1
Union All 
Select patient.pid,title, fname, mname, lname, religion from patient 
INNER JOIN patient_address ON patient.pid = patient_address.pid
WHERE 1=1` the error is as follows. " Error code 245, SQL state 22018: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'TMP1000001' to data type int." One type is int and other is varchar.

Comment: i have overseen your patientID is a varchar(15) field. i've edited my post with a convert